# Concatenate cells

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell

I have two cells,

```
A =
 [100x2 double]    [80x2 double]    [50x2 double]
B =
 [100x5 double]    [80x5 double]    [50x5 double]
```

How can I Concatenate them to get something like `C = cat(2,A,B)` for each array. `C` must be,

```
C =
 [100x7 double]    [80x7 double]    [50x7 double]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
C = cellfun(@(a, b) [a b], A, B, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

This will create the cell array C for you.

Example:

```
>> A = { zeros(100,2), zeros(200,2) };
>> B = { ones(100,5), ones(200,5)};
>> C = cellfun(@(a, b) [a b], A, B, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know you could pass _two_ cell arrays to `cellfun`

Comment: how can this be generalized to multiple cell arrays a,b,c,d...?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need some kind of loop:

```
C = arrayfun(@(n) [A{:,n} B{:,n}], 1:numel(A), 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

Of course, if the number of cells in `A` (and `B`) is fixed, you can replace the loop by an enumeration:

```
C = {[A{:,1} B{:,1}] [A{:,2} B{:,2}] [A{:,3} B{:,3}]};
```